# trying to make a shell script that sends me and email if an ip address goes down

Tags: shell

Hello
i am trying to make a shell script that checks for a ping response. if there is no response i want it to send me an email telling me that it is down.

What i am trying to do is to receive an email if one of my switches go down.

this is going to run as a cronjob btw
thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: so i created a script while ping -c 3 172.16.0.255 | grep $reponse;
if $reponse = "Request";
mail -s "Advertising switch is down" emailaddress@gmail.com
else    
exit0
of coarse i am using incorrect syntax. the two examples are very helpful yet they arn't quite working the way i need them to. i am fairly new to shell scripting so i am not sure exactly how to declare variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if ping's return value is standardized, so check the documentation for your ping, but if your ping returns a reasonable value then you can simply do:

```
while ping -c 1 $IP; do
  sleep $TIMEOUT
done
mail -s "$IP is down" email@address
```

("Reasonable value" meaning zero if at least one response is received.  BSD ping satisfies that condition.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested, but it should give you the idea how to solve this:

```
ping -c 1 <SOME IP> | grep "1 received" || echo "I lost connection" | mail -s "link is down!!" you@example.com
```

Comment: You mean `echo`, not `cat` unless you have a file named "I lost connection".